# Can i pass a parameter to jackson custom serializer

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I am in the process of creating a number web services. Many of these return objects that contain properties that are stored in the database table as codes. These codes are stored in a table where pick list values are given a type. When these codes appear on the normal desktop application, the JSP transforms these into user friendly code descriptions.
I need to transform any codes normally transformed in the JSP to a set format, the code and the description separated by a | before returning the response. 
I thought it would be a good idea to write a jackson custom serializer class that would do this. I could then annotate any methods @JsonSerialize, returning a code, to serialize using this custom class. The problem is I need to pass the type of code to the custom serializer class to know which code to search for. So basically I need to pass a parameter in my @JsonSerialize annotation but as I don't think this is possible, any thoughts on a work around.
My custom serializer looks like this... (I need to pass the type to this class somehow)

```
@Component
public class MaintCodeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

  @Autowired
  private MaintCodeService maintCodeService;
  public MaintCodeSerializer(){
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);    
  }
  @Override
  public void serialize(String code, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    MaintCodeVO maintCode = maintCodeService.retrieveMaintCode(type, code);
    jgen.writeString(maintCode.getCodeAndDescResponse());
  }

}
```

The pojo getter looks like this...

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MaintCodeSerializer.class)
  public String getIntelCategory()
  {
     return intelCategory;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a BeanSerializerModifier.

First of all you have to create one annotation with your own needs. Then you create a BeanSerializerModifier, override "changeProperties"  method that creates the correct JsonSerializer to whom you can pass the arguments of the annotation to the serializer's constructor.

Last step, register your BeanSerializerModifier by adding a new Module to ObjectMapper.